# How to create a recursive structure in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, recursive-datastructures

I have a categories table which has three fields: `Id`, `Title`, and `ParentId`. I'd like to create a recursive hierarchical structure of my table (a tree) in a cshtml file. I'm new to ASP.NET MVC and I don't know how to do that, because there is no code-behind file and I don't know from where should I start. Please note that I'm storing a **jungle**, not a **tree** in my database. In other words, the result tree can have many roots.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The easiest is using a helper:

```
@helper RecurseSomething(MyClass data) {
    <li>
        @data.Title
        @if (data.SubItems.Count() > 0) {
           <ul>
              @foreach(var subData in data.SubItems) {
                  @RecurseSomething(subData);
              }
           </ul>
        }    
    </li>
}
```

Comment: Genius! Simple yet powerful.